# SQL Sum by Category and group by month/year

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, categories

Attempting to sum the total product manufactured by type and summarized by month/year.

Three tables:

- **Order_Line**: id, batch_date_stop, item_id
- **Order_Line_Detail**:  order_line_id, batched_qty, item_id
- **Mill_Item_Map**:  item_id, item_class

The below script works but is making a separate line for each category each month.  I would like one line with a total of each product.  What am I missing?

```
SELECT
YEAR(OL.batch_date_stop) as [Manf Year],
MONTH(OL.batch_date_stop) as [Manf Month],
SUM(case when MIM.item_class is not null then OLD.batched_qty else 0 end)/2000 AS Total,
SUM(case when MIM.item_class = 'CAKE' then OLD.batched_qty else 0 end)/2000 AS [Cake],
SUM(case when MIM.item_class = 'PELLET' then OLD.batched_qty end)/2000 AS [Pellet],
SUM(case when MIM.item_class = 'MINERAL' then OLD.batched_qty end)/2000 AS [Mineral],
SUM(case when MIM.item_class = 'MIX' then OLD.batched_qty end)/2000 AS [Mix],
SUM(case when MIM.item_class = 'GRAIN' then OLD.batched_qty end)/2000 AS [Grain]
FROM Order_Line OL
JOIN order_line_detail OLD ON OLD.order_line_id = OL.id
JOIN mill_item_map MIM ON MIM.item_id = OL.item_id
WHERE YEAR(OL.batch_date_stop) = 2016 and
OLD.sequence_number = 0
Group BY MIM.item_class, YEAR(OL.batch_date_stop), MONTH(OL.batch_date_stop)
ORDER BY YEAR(OL.batch_date_stop), MONTH(OL.batch_date_stop)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think min.item_class can ever be null you are doing an inner join to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using only year and month in group by

```
Group BY  YEAR(OL.batch_date_stop), MONTH(OL.batch_date_stop)
```